# Push provisioning - Add card to apple and google wallet in react-native

Tags: react-native, google-pay, android-pay, card, apple-wallet

I am working on a project, In which I need to add debit cards to Apple/Google Wallet, I have debit card details so How can I add that to Apple/Google Wallet with react-native?

Comment: For Google Pay, as a first step, you need to get access to the push provisioning docs: https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/

Comment: This library should work well for IOS. I'm not sure about Google Wallet implementation yet https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wallet-manager